# Improve performance of select on select query using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

As for Table structure, the table has weekly product prices for per country.
My goal here is to select the lowest price of each product for the most recent week/year per country per product. 
The query below fulfills this goal, but is pretty slow performance wise. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing the same task.

In the first part Im selecting the latest Year and week of prices per country. I included the CASE When to account for new year. 
Im saving this in a #temptable.
Then I am selecting  the min price based on the previous selected Year, Week and Country combo.

```
DECLARE @date DATE SET @date=getdate()

SELECT YearNb, Max(WeekNb) AS WeekNb, ISOCountryCode INTO #TempTable FROM PriceBenchWeekly  
WHERE PriceBenchWeekly.YearNb = CASE WHEN DATEPART(ww,@date)  = 1 THEN
                Year(@date)-1
                ELSE
                Year(@date)
                END
GROUP BY YearNb, ISOCountryCode

SELECT ProdNb,Min(WeeklyPrice) AS MinPrice, MarketPlayerCode, 'MKT' AS PriceOriginTypeCode, NatCoCode
FROM CE.PriceBenchWeekly INNER JOIN #TempTable ON PriceBenchWeekly.YearNb = #TempTable.YearNb AND 
PriceBenchWeekly.WeekNb = #TempTable.WeekNb AND PriceBenchWeekly.ISOCountryCode = #TempTable.ISOCountryCode

GROUP BY PriceBenchweekly.YearNb, PriceBenchWeekly.ISOCountryCode, BNCode, MarketPlayerCode
```

Comment: I suspect that case statement is throwing off your performance. Run the query with show plan on and see what it tells you (paste image in)

Comment: Which part is the problem? And how many records are you handling?

Answer (score 3):

> the table has weekly product prices for per country. My goal here is to select the lowest price of each product for the most recent week/year per country per product.

Use window functions.  Without sample data and desired results, it is a little hard to figure out what you really want.  But the following gets the minimum price for each product from the most recent week in the data:

```
select pbw.*
from (select pbw.*,
             min(weeklyprice) over (partition by prodnb) as min_weeklyprice
      from (select pbw.*,
                   dense_rank() over (order by year desc, weeknb desc) as seqnum
            from CE.PriceBenchWeekly pbw
           ) pbw
      where seqnum = 1
     ) pbw
where weeklyprice = min_weeklyprice;
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer, this looks very interesting Im still pretty new to SQL so I didnt even know about this. Im sorry for not being specific enough in my original post. This already almost does what I want, its just missing the country component, meaning I need the minimum price for each product PER COUNTRY from the most recent week. I will play around with this a bit, maybe I can get it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with temp tables, do not create it using select into, use CREATE TABLE #TempTable instead, then you can create a non clustered index for Year, Week and Country code...

Anyway, I would prefer outer apply

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ProductCode, A.CountryCode, B.YearNo, B.WeekNo, B.MinPrice
FROM YourTable A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 YearNo, WeekNo, Min(Price) AS MinPrice
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE ProductCode = A.ProductCode AND CountryCode = B.CountryCode
    GROUP BY YearNo, WeekNo
    ORDER BY YearNo DESC, WeekNo DESC
) B
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will look into it! I still have to get a better understanding of the whole indexing part, that seems to be very powerful from what I can gather.